# Is there an instance where Rome adopted a weapon to win a war?

Tags: ancient-rome, ancient-greece

I thought I had read that Roman soldiers had adopted crossbows to defeat the Pythagoreans. However after Google and Wikipedia, I can't find support for this.

Or was there some other example where the Romans successfully adopted an enemy weapon to use against the enemy?

Comment: What are "Pythagoreans"?

Comment: Pythagoreans were followers of the philosophy of Pythagoras, and unlikely to have been a significant military threat to Rome.  You may be thinking of Romans copying Carthaginian ships during the first Punic War.

Comment: Or of the invention of the corvus (also during the first Punic War). Anyway, military commanders of any age need to be resourceful to counter enemy threats; v.g. in the conquest of the Balearic Islands it is reported that the Romans had to cover their ships with hides to protect them from the native slingers; what counts as an adaptation or what counts as just an "invention" is clearly argueable, as it is the impact of any particular technique (could the Romans have won Carthague without the corvus?)

Comment: Altough the question needs serious improvements, I think it is valid. I think in context what were the adopted elements in Roman warfare, answers could provide interesting facts.

Comment: I have hopefully clarified the question and suggest that it NOT be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about speculative history

Answer (score 2):

The Romans "borrowed" the Carthaginian [trireme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trireme) to win the Punic wars, using one that had been "beached" as a model.

They added a "corvus" or hook, to allow them to board, since they were better at land fighting.

Answer (score 0):

In an article about the Column of Trajan I read that the Romans temporarily adopted arm armor (like that used by some gladiators)  during the Dacian War because some of the allies of the Dacians were known for cutting off arms in battle - "disarming" their enemies.